# Calculate account receivables of Customers

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate list all Customers A/C Receivables.
I calculate list of sales and receipts of customers, now I'm stuck how to calculate Receivables.

**All Customer's Sales Report**

```
Select c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName, sum(s.Amount) as TotalSales from
StakeHolders c
left Join Sales s on
c.StakeHolderId = s.BuyerId
where c.StakeHolderTypeId = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
group By c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName
```

**All Customer's Receipts**

```
Select c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName, sum(pr.Amount) as TotalReceipts 
from
StakeHolders c
left Join PaymentsAndReceipts pr on
c.StakeHolderId = pr.StakeHolderId
where c.StakeHolderTypeId = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
group By c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName
```

**I have tried this but didn't get the right result.**

```
Select
c.StakeHolderId,
c.CompanyName,
sum(s.Amount) - sum(pr.Amount) as Receivables
from Sales s
right outer join StakeHolders c on
c.StakeHolderId = s.BuyerId
left outer join PaymentsAndReceipts pr on
pr.StakeHolderId = c.StakeHolderId
where c.StakeHolderTypeId = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
Group By c.StakeHolderId,c.CompanyName
```

**expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: give us some sample data and expected result

Comment: thanks for your quick reply sir, I have update image link in question.

Comment: your link returns with 404 Not Found, you may want to upload it on your own post?

Comment: Link seems broken

Comment: image is uploaded.

Comment: How about the result for first 2 queries? "All Customer's Sales Report" and "All Customer's Receipts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
WITH [CalculatedData] AS
(
    SELECT
        C.[StakeHolderId],
        C.[CompanyName],
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM([Amount])
                  FROM [Sales]
                  WHERE [BuyerId] = C.[StakeHolderId]
                 ), 0) AS [TotalSales],
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM([Amount])
                  FROM [PaymentsAndReceipts]
                  WHERE [StakeHolderId] = C.[StakeHolderId]
                 ), 0) AS [TotalReceipts]

    FROM
        [StakeHolders] AS C
    WHERE
        C.[StakeHolderTypeId] = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
)
SELECT
    [StakeHolderId],
    [CompanyName],
    [TotalSales] - [TotalReceipts] AS [Receivables]
FROM
    [CalculatedData]
```

Note that I include negative values in the result. If you want negative values shown between parentheses, that's possible too, but it will require conversion of numerical data to textual data in the query results. IMHO, that's not a flexible strategy (since you lose the option to perform any additional client-side calculations) and it should be the client's purpose to correctly format the values.

Edit:

If you don't like Common Table Expressions, you can convert it to a regular table expression:

```
SELECT
    [StakeHolderId],
    [CompanyName],
    [TotalSales] - [TotalReceipts] AS [Receivables]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            C.[StakeHolderId],
            C.[CompanyName],
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM([Amount])
                      FROM [Sales]
                      WHERE [BuyerId] = C.[StakeHolderId]
                     ), 0) AS [TotalSales],
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM([Amount])
                      FROM [PaymentsAndReceipts]
                      WHERE [StakeHolderId] = C.[StakeHolderId]
                     ), 0) AS [TotalReceipts]

        FROM
            [StakeHolders] AS C
        WHERE
            C.[StakeHolderTypeId] = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
    ) AS [CalculatedData]
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks @BartHofland

Answer (score 0):

just take first query LEFT JOIN to second query join by StakeHolderId & companyname. After that take sales subtract receipts

```
SELECT S.StakeHolderId, S.CompanyName, 
       Receivables = TotalSales - ISNULL(TotalReceipts , 0)
FROM
(
    -- this is your first query
    Select c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName, sum(s.Amount) as TotalSales from
    StakeHolders c
    left Join Sales s on
    c.StakeHolderId = s.BuyerId
    where c.StakeHolderTypeId = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
    group By c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName
) S
LEFT JOIN
(
    -- this is your second query
    Select c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName, sum(pr.Amount) as TotalReceipts 
    from
    StakeHolders c
    left Join PaymentsAndReceipts pr on
    c.StakeHolderId = pr.StakeHolderId
    where c.StakeHolderTypeId = '0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10'
    group By c.StakeHolderId, c.CompanyName
) R    ON S.StakeHolderId = R.StakeHolderId
      AND S.CompanyName   = R.CompanyName
```